# Python Multiprocessing DictProxy append to dict of list not working

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a program that uses a multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy. The program traverses a directory, and creates a dict with username as the key obtained by `pwd.getpwuid(os.stat(file)[4])[0]`, and the corresponding value to the key would be a list that contains the files owned by that user. Eg for the supposed datastructure:

```
{'root': ["/boot/vmlinuz", "/boot/grub"], 'testuser': ["/home/testuser", "/home/testuser/.bashrc"]}
```

The code I wrote to do this is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import multiprocessing
import sys
import pwd
import grp
manager_attributes = multiprocessing.Manager()
file_stats_user = manager_attributes.dict()    
def filestat(file):
  try:
      stat = os.stat(file)
      user = pwd.getpwuid(stat[4])[0]
      group = grp.getgrgid(stat[5])[0]
      if user not in file_stats_user:
          file_stats_user[user] = []
      file_stats_user[user].append(file)
  except OSError, e:
      print e

try:
    cores = (multiprocessing.cpu_count()*2)
except:
    cores = 8
print "Starting parallel execution with ", cores, "concurrency"
pool_get_attributes = multiprocessing.Pool(cores)
pool_get_attributes.map(filestat, files)
pool_get_attributes.close()
pool_get_attributes.join()
```

where files is a list of all the files obtained.

However, when I am printing the file_stats_user which is a multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy object, I am getting the keys, but the list values are empty, as

```
{'root': [], 'testuser': []}
```

`file_stats_user[user].append(file)` is not appending the file name to the respective key.
What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: when using `multiprocessing`, you must protect the main module with `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** the previous solution has a race condition if two process update the dict for the same user in the same time

Your solution don't work because by default a list is local to the current process and the update made to it is not proxied.

For making working, you should use a list which is a proxy so it could be updated in all process

replace

```
file_stats_user[user] = []
```

by

```
file_stats_user[user] = manager_attributes.list()
```

Now when you append to list it is the same on all process

**But** using a shared object is a bad way to do multiprocess

A better way is to gather the results of each call

```
from collections import defaultdict
def filestat(file):
  try:
      stat = os.stat(file)
      user = pwd.getpwuid(stat[4])[0]
      group = grp.getgrgid(stat[5])[0]
      return user, file
  except OSError, e:
      print e
      return None
try:
    cores = (multiprocessing.cpu_count()*2)
except:
    cores = 8
print "Starting parallel execution with ", cores, "concurrency"
pool_get_attributes = multiprocessing.Pool(cores)
result_map = pool_get_attributes.map(filestat, files)
result = defaultdict(list)
for user,file in (r for r in result_map if r is not None):
    result[user].append(file)
pool_get_attributes.close()
pool_get_attributes.join()
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain, what does `file_stats_user[user] = file_stats_user[user]+[file]` do, and why the append didn't worked? I didn't understand what `file_stats_user[user] = file_stats_user[user]+[file] ` does.

Comment: I updated my answer. 
What  `file_stats_user[user] = file_stats_user[user]+[file]` did  is creating a new list with one element more and updating the dict with it
**However**, between the time the new list is created and the time the update happen, another process could have already updated the dict and the second update would overwrite the first update, so losing data

Comment: Well, the edited answer now makes perfect sense to a beginner like me. Thanks a lot. So I guess I'll have to use `defaultdict()`.

Comment: And I changed from `os.stat` to `os.lstat()`, that doesn't follow symlinks.